# Reference of hadith regarding fitnahs near day of judgement?

Tags: hadith, hadith-interpretation, uloom-al-hadith, day-of-judgement

What is the reference of hadith, whose approximate meaning is that near judgement day ,whoever will look towards a fitnah will be trapped into fitnah?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean I found [this hadith](https://sunnah.com/ibnmajah:3968) which was also compiled by abu Dawod and ibn Majah with another sanad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The closest I could find is the sahih hadith:

> Allah's Messenger (ﷺ) said, "There will be afflictions (and at the time) the sitting person will be better than the standing one, and the standing one will be better than the walking, and the walking will be better than the running. And **whoever will look towards those afflictions, they will overtake him**, and whoever will find a refuge or a shelter, should take refuge in it."
> The same narration is reported by Abu Bakr, with the addition, "(The Prophet (ﷺ) said), 'Among the prayers there is a prayer the missing of which will be to one like losing one's family and property."
> (Sahih al-Bukhari in the Chapter [Virtues and Merits of the Prophet (pbuh) and his Companions](https://sunnah.com/bukhari:3601) and also in Afflictions and the End of the World [here](https://sunnah.com/bukhari:7081) and [here](https://sunnah.com/bukhari:7082))

Imam Muslim also compiled it in "The Book of Tribulations and Portents of the Last Hour" on the authority of [abu Hurairah](https://sunnah.com/muslim:2886a) and [abu Bakra](https://sunnah.com/muslim:2887a).

Further imam at-Thirmidi can be counted among the scholars who compiled a part of this hadith as you may read [here](https://sunnah.com/tirmidhi:2194).
One could also count ibn Hebban (in his Sahih), al-Bayhaqi (in his as-Sunan al-Kubra), imam Ahmad (in his al-Musnad), At-Tabarani (in his al-Moa'jam al-Awsat on the autorithy of abu Musa), ibn Abi Shaybah (in his al-Mosannaf) and abu Dawod at-Tayalissi (in his al-Musnad) among those who quoted parts of the hadith.

I'll concentrate now on sources that quote the hadith including the meaning you requested -as far as I understood-:

- Ibn Hebban in his Sahih see here hadith #[5959](https://al-maktaba.org/book/1729/8743)
- al-Aajurri in his a-Shari'a see [here](https://al-maktaba.org/book/13035/87) and [here](https://al-maktaba.org/book/13035/88)
- Abu Ya'ala al-Moosili in his Musnad see [here](https://al-maktaba.org/book/32852/5981).

Main reference for tkhreej of the hadith was [islamarchive.cc](https://islamarchive.cc/H_183845) and islamweb (see for example [here](https://www.islamweb.net/ar/library/index.php?page=bookcontents&idfrom=6778&idto=6779&bk_no=0&ID=3910)).